# how to check the size of the image file in javaserver faces

Tags: image, jsf, image-upload

I m working on javaserver faces i had problem with checking the size of the image file uploaded ,can any one help me ?

Comment: With the size, do you mean the image content length or the image dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `java.io.File.length()` for getting size.

getting file size by `java.io.File.length()` is ok but it is slow .instead it you can use fileChannel's `size` method.it is littlebit faster than j`ava.io.File.length()`

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                File me = new File(your file path).getFile());
                fis = new FileInputStream(me);
                return fis.getChannel().size();
            } finally {
                fis.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your are using for file uploading but you could check 'content-length' header of uploaded file.

Or if your  were using 'Apache commons fileupload' you could do it like so

```
   ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    upload.setFileItemFactory(new DiskFileItemFactory());
    List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

    for(int i=0; i < fileItems.size(); i++){
       FileItem item = (FileItem)fileItems.get(i);
       if(item.isFormField() == true){
          if(item.getFieldName() !=null  ){
             int fileSize = item.get().length ;
          }
       }
    }
```